# Sent JSON Array is empty when recieved in another php page

Tags: php, json

I send an array from form1.php to form2.php

```
<input id="hidden_all_headers" type="hidden" name="hidden_all_headers" value="<?php echo json_encode($all_headers_array); ?>">
```

The inspector in form1.php

```
<input id="hidden_all_headers" type="hidden" name="hidden_all_headers" **value="[" region","countries_of_origin","visits_in_milions","receipts_in_milions_euro","nights_in_thousands","expenditure_per_visit_euro","cost_per_night_euro","average_length_of_stay"]"="">**
```

****which looks fine.. but in form2.php****

```
--html
<input id="hidden_all_headers" type="hidden" name="hidden_all_headers" value="<?php echo json_decode($_POST['hidden_all_headers'],true); ?>">       
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var obj = "<?php echo json_decode($_POST['hidden_all_headers']) ?>";
for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
alert(obj[i]);
};
</script>
```

inspector for form2.php

```
-- html

<input id="hidden_all_headers" type="hidden" name="hidden_all_headers" **value=""**>

--script
**var obj = "";**
for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
alert(obj[i]);
};
$('#hidden_all_headers').val(obj);
```

Can you please help me out why I can not receive the array in form2.php?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings/notices present? If you dump `$_POST` in `form2.php`, what do you get?

Comment: Though this part surely can't work: `<?php echo json_decode($_POST['hidden_all_headers'],true); ?>` as you can't echo an array.

Comment: _"which looks fine...*_ - no it doesn't. You've wrapped your `value` attribute in double quotes, but your JSON wraps all it's keys and values in double quotes too. The result is a mess that the browser can't make sense of.

Comment: @El_Vanja apache log: ** Undefined index: hidden_all_headers in C:\\xampp_new\\htdocs\\ProcessLoader\\www\\DataTableManager\\form2.php on line 88, referer: http://localhost/ProcessLoader/www/DataTableManager/form1.php**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes for your HTML elements should be generally wrapped in double-quotes (there are exceptions but the don't really apply here). JSON data wraps all its keys and values in double quotes too, so your value attribute looks like this:

```
value="[" region","countries_of_origin","visits_in_milions","receipts_in_milions_euro","nights_in_thousands","expenditure_per_visit_euro","cost_per_night_euro","average_length_of_stay"]"=""
```

See how the double-quotes open and close in all the wrong places. The browser can't make sense of it, so it ignores it all.

Your solution is to encode the JSON data using `htmlspecialchars()`

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($all_headers_array)); ?>"
```

So, starting from this:

```
{"val1":"value1","val2":"value2"}
```

This will give you a value attribute like this:

```
value="{&quot;val1&quot;:&quot;value1&quot;,&quot;val2&quot;:&quot;value2&quot;}"
```

To use that value in your PHP you need to decode it with `htmlspecialchars_decode()` and then `json_decode()` it.

However, I would question why you're sending this data to a form in the first place. Doesn't your server already know what it should be getting?

Comment: problem solved thanks to your solution! thanks!

Comment: @HoomanSeddighi Glad to be of help. Please remember to accept my answer.